# Obtener el valor en tiempo real en mi v-autocomplete en vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Hola estoy aprendiendo a usar vue para desarrollo front-end, estoy haciendo un blog y cuando voy a empezar a crear un componente tag-selecter me encuentro con este problema, estoy usando el componente de vuetify v-autocomplete.

en teoria este codigo deberia funcionar pero no lo hace, solo me devuelve el ultimo caracter escrito pero no todo lo que hay en el input

```
 <template>
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="selectedItem"
      :items="items"
      label="Select an item"
      @input="handleInput"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </template>
  <script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        selectedItem: "null",
        items: [
          'Item 1',
          'Item 2',
          'Item 3',
          // Agrega más elementos según sea necesario
        ],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleInput(newValue) {
        // `newValue` contendrá el valor actual del componente v-autocomplete
        // Puedes realizar acciones con cada cambio de entrada aquí
        console.log(newValue.data);

        
      },
    },
  };
  </script>
```

alguien que me ayude? se lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

You can add the title property as follows:

```
    <v-autocomplete
  label="Autocomplete"
  :items="CountList"
  variant="outlined"
  :item-title="item => item"
>
</v-autocomplete>
```